# 'unexpected token' in PowerShell when fully pathing executable

Tags: powershell

Just trying to better understand why the second item below does not work. The first item is simple, the second seems clearer, the third seems unintuitive.

```
# My path includes pscp so this works.
pscp.exe -i $PRIVATE_KEY $file ${PROXY_USER}@${PROXY_HOST}:${PROXY_DIR}

# This does not work. I get unexpected token error. Why? What does that mean?
$PUTTY_PATH\pscp.exe -i $PRIVATE_KEY $file ${PROXY_USER}@${PROXY_HOST}:${PROXY_DIR}

# & is required to solve the problem.
& "$PUTTY_PATH\pscp.exe" -i $PRIVATE_KEY $file ${PROXY_USER}@${PROXY_HOST}:${PROXY_DIR}
```

Comment: Side note: it is also usually a good idea to wrap all of your arguments in strings to prevent the PowerShell parser from messing with them. I have had issues before trying to use $FolderPath\* and -p$Password as arguments to an executable, where as "$FolderPath\*" and "-p$Password" will always work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because this is also considered a parse error:

```
"foo"\pscp.exe
```

Whereas this parses correctly as you have found:

```
"$PUTTY_PATH\pscp.exe"
```

That resolves to a valid string but as you have already noticed, a string doesn't execute.  You have to use the call operator `&` to invoke the command that is named by the string that follows.

Answer (score 0):

It's taking the `\` to be part of the variable name, and complains because it is not legal.  If you are using this snippet like i would, by putting it into a .ps1 file in your path, then i would just cd over to $putty_path if you don't want to have pscp.exe in your global PATH env var.

Comment: No, it's not that. Besides, Backslashes in variable names *are* legal, they just require another syntax to access (namely `${var\name}`).

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but I have a feeling you might be misusing the curly braces. Are you trying to get the environment variable PROXY_USER instead? Typically the curly brackets are used for starting a new statement block.

```
$Env:PROXY_USER
```

Also, you may want to encapsulate that proxy info inside a string to ensure it is treated as a single argument:

```
"$Env:PROXY_USER@$Env:PROXY_HOST:$Env:PROXY_DIR"
```